# Why my code Django into HTMl variables didnt work

Tags: python, html, django

I’m trying to get a variable into a html document with python and django

```
def nombrarVariables(request):

 nombre="juan"
 doc_externo=open("SeleccionGrafica2.html")

 template=Template(doc_externo.read())
 doc_externo.close()

 contexto=Context({"variable": nombre})
 documento=template.render(contexto)

return HttpResponse(documento)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this snippet in a more concise way:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def nombrarVariables(request):

    nombre = 'juan'
    context = {'nombre': nombre}
    return render(request, 'SeleccionGrafica2.html', context)
```

In your template you can access your variable with `{{nombre}}` and in the render function change the path of your templates regarding your file structure